# Is the save data for Angry Birds still there even if the app isn't?

Tags: cyanogenmod, angry-birds

Recently I've been playing around with the Cyanogen nightlies on my N1. Nightly cm7 1-8 were fine but then one day I lost the home button so I had to backup and then wipe and then eventually everything was fine. But after the wipe Angry Birds was gone and even after I restore I don't have Angry Birds installed. If I install it is the save data still there?

Side note, when you do a backup with one Titianium, does it backup the save data too? Is that only if you have root? How would a non-root user do a backup? And why is the save data not just a database file somewhere that is easy to backup? Is the integrity of scores at risk or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you backed up from Recovery, correct?  If that is the case, then the backup should contain *everything* that was on your phone before the backup -- apps, saved games, etc.  So restoring the backup should have restored Angry Birds and its save data, as long as that was present before the backup.

Titanium can back up the app, the app's data, or both.  It does require root.  Non-root users have to deal with Recovery backups, which are not as flexible since you can't restore only bits and pieces -- it's all or nothing.  Of course, the SD card is easy to back up (plug it into a computer) and some apps may allow you to export data.

You'd have to ask Rovio why they chose not to use a database, but I'd guess it's because the save data is so simple.  If you open the file it's almost human-readable text.  Even easier to back up than a database.

Comment: I can't find the backup that I did after having to manually boot into recover. The only ones there are the same as the ones that happen when I do a backup from ROM Manager and it does them in recovery too. I've restored every backup and NONE of them have Angry Birds installed except the one from January. Almost everything I store on my phone is either on the SD card or the cloud EXCEPT Angry Birds saves.

Comment: That sucks.  But I guess the January save is better than starting from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, I have accepted my fate and now I know if I want to mess with the latest mods I need to keep good backups of Angry Birds . . . crazy I made it this long and never lost anything. Even going from 2.2 to 2.3 and I SWEAR I've wiped data before.